# Core data with primary key

Tags: iphone, core-data

I want to retrieve data from core data (sqlite database) according to primary key. it is displaying data in ascending or descending order.. ordering of data is not like database..
my code is:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tutorial" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Topic" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code says

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Topic" ascending:NO];
```

so your result will be sorted by the field "Topic" in descending order

maybe

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
```

don't think you should be using "id" in coredata unless u are migrating from some legacy database

Comment: i used this but not working because i have only topic and description field in core data model.. I used Z_PK from sqlite also but not working.should I create id field in model?

Comment: generally you don't need "id"field in model. if you have only "topic" and "description" then those are you only option to sort retrieved data by. I might be a little confuse in what you are trying to do

Comment: Why do you want to sort by ID? Is the end goal to order by time of creation?

Comment: this is like a tutorial app...i added topics like introduction,history,syntax this all should be in order... anyways I added Id field in model..and sort it by id.. Thanks for giving ur time

Comment: @user640780 -- If you are attempting to write to the SQLite file directly, you are likely to corrupt it. Moreover, the fields in the SQL fields to not necessarily map directly to the managed objects. Don't make the mistake of thinking that Core Data is just an object wrapper for SQL.